# Azure Function receiving duplicate messages from Event Grid

Tags: azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventgrid

I've a very simple Javascript Function App being sent messages from an Event Grid subscription with a filter. The function reliably gets **two** messages for every **one** that arrives at the IoT Hub that the Event Grid is being fed by.

I've verified that it *is* only one message by also routing the same message to storage using the same filter (using IoT Hub Message Routing).

I do not believe it's the timeout "error" I see noted while searching on this: the function processes in 10-150ms and definitely isn't running against the 30 second retry timer. The repeated messages come in within milliseconds of each other, the second immediately following the first.

Also, the messages are byte-for-byte identical, and they have the same trigger timestamp and Id:

`Executing 'Functions.processLocationSetupMsg' (Reason='EventGrid trigger fired at 2020-12-01T02:08:14.6659970+00:00', Id=2734288c-c758-4a8e-b843-d6b12d0304b7)`

The function is basically from the docs and looks like this:

```js
module.exports = async function(context, eventGridEvent) {
    let out = (eventGridEvent.data.body && eventGridEvent.data.body.model) ?
        eventGridEvent.data.body.model :
        "model not defined"
    context.log(`>>> JavaScript eventgrid trigger function called for message: ${out}`);

    context.log(JSON.stringify(eventGridEvent, null, 2))
};
```

I have also tried the non-async style using `context.done()`, too.

The Event Subscription Filter is `data.body.model` `string begins with` `locationSetup`.

Any thoughts how I might get this down to just one message as expected?

Comment: In case it helps, I'm seeing the duplicates via `context.log()`ing and watching the logs by streaming them into VS Code (Mac).

Comment: Do you have more than one subscription to the EG topic (or domain) ?

Comment: No, just the one. Spent a lot of time with MS on this (had a service ticket). We were never able to identify it, and then it went away with no code change. Kind of unsatisfying result, but the functions all work, so <shrug>.